# Fixed points of cardinal logarithm

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic

For any cardinal $\kappa$ set $$\log(\kappa) = \min\{\mu\in \kappa\cup\{\kappa\}: 2^\mu  \geq \kappa\}.$$
Clearly $\log(\omega) = \omega$ and in $\textsf{GCH}$ we have $\log(\aleph_\omega) = \aleph_\omega$.

Is it consistent that $\log(\kappa)<\kappa$ for all uncountable cardinals $\kappa$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Because strong limits cardinals exist in $\sf ZFC$. These are the $\beth_\alpha$ for a non-successor $\alpha$.

Comment: And without choice?

Comment: You have to be more careful, but there is a reasonable sense in which the same statement is provable without choice.